# AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord makes AirPlay invisible

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, airplay, avaudiosession

I am encountering the following problem: AirPlay becomes not available whenever I set play-and-record category to the audio session in my application:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
        setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
        error: &setCategoryError];
```

This call makes the AirPlay disappear and reroutes the audio to the speaker immediately.

The problem can be easily reproduced e.g. on the sample project `avTouch` from Xcode documentation by replacing `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` category with  `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`: in the original example AirPlay picker is visible and allows to change output source, whereas with the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category the picker disappears.

Is there a proper way to switch to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category so that the AirPlay is still available?

(A question like this has been [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319100/avaudiosessioncategoryplayandrecord-with-airplay), but didn't get any answer.)

Comment: Probably you might have to try with some private APIs. Check if this helps in anyway. http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/04/23/ios-mirroring-and-programmatic-airplay-selection/ They are mentioning some private apis.

Comment: @ACB: thank you! I looked at the mentioned article, but as you say, they are using private APIs, which I cannot use, as the project I am working for is distributed through App Store.

Comment: @Anastasia Have you got an solution? I'm facing the same issue with you.Thanks

Comment: @Jacky No, I have no solution. Jonathan Arbogast's idea sounds likely though.

Answer (score 1):

What AirPlay device are you trying to use? Does it have a microphone?

If not, iOS won't present it as an option when using the PlayAndRecord category, because that device can't play **and** record. It would show up when using the Play category though.

Also, if the device you are using is a Bluetooth device, have you set AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth to YES?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the code below above `AVAudioSession`. I hope it works.

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

if (setCategoryError) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, AirPlay and the PlayAndRecord category are just incompatible.
That's what I learned from the Apple forums.

Why do you need audio input on the device when audio output happens somewhere else?

Comment: The application plays back a video stream (possibly outputting the sound through AirPlay) and records the said stream at the same time. Makes sense?

Comment: The point is, the audio works as expected for plugged-in headphones, so it was my natural assumption that AirPlay-connected headphones should work the same way.

Comment: -1: There are so many reasons why you might want it.  A customer of mine wishes to use my audio monitoring software to perform a room response check by playing out audio over airplay and then monitoring what the iPhone records (in measurement mode).  So annoying that apple block this completely.